# Error message with Python jira-agile-metrics package - name 'jira' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, jira, jira-agile

I am fairly new to Python and I am trying to use the jira-agile-metrics package to get metrics from our Jira project. As I read the documentation for the jira-agile-metrics, the instruction is to use the Python command line. After installing the package successfully, whenever I try any the commands listed in the documentation, I get the error message "name 'jira' is not defined.', starting by a single jira-agile-metrics --help command.

I checked the directory where the package is installed, checked also the yaml config file location that I created, and it seems that everything is in place correctly.

Can someone give me some direction on what I am missing?
Is it possible to use an IDE with this package instead of the command line?

Here is the documentation: https://pypi.org/project/jira-agile-metrics/#description

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!
Here is the screenshot of the error:
[image: jira-agile-metrics_notdefined_error]

I also tried this:
[image: jira-agile-metrics_notdefined-help]

Comment: Did you reload your console after the `pip install jira-agile-metrics` command?

Comment: Hi, @MarceloPaco.

Comment: Hi, @MarceloPaco. I tried .reload() but I got the same error. I also tried to run it in the iPython Console in my Spider IDE, which has as settings to Enable UMR checked (User Module Reloader), but it didn't work either. Any thoughts?

Comment: I am not using docker as it is an option stated in the documentation.

Comment: How are you installing `jira-agile-metrics`? I just followed the instructions on the document you linked and got `jira-agile-metrics --help` command working. Also, what is your version of python?

Comment: My python version is 3.8.10. I installed the package with pip - "pip install jira-agile-metrics"

Comment: Can you add to your question the error code you got instead of your typed one?

Comment: Hi @MarceloPaco, I attached a screenshot. Could it be something related to the pythonpath?

Comment: The `jira-agile-metrics` command can't be used in an `Ipython` console. It can be used in `command prompt` (windows) or in a `terminal` (linux).

Comment: @MarceloPaco, both in command prompt and terminal I get the same thing. Not sure at this point, but I am investigating if it might be related to the path.